# Problem with regex parsing

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a problem parsing a line with regex

This is the line it will parse (called string Line)

```
4\:0=10.000000\:20,0.000000\:1,0\:0
```

this is the code to seperate it in pieces:

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split(Line, "\\");
```

but it says:

```
"\" invalid \ at the end of the pattern
```

dunno what is means...

Comment: Why are you even using Regex.Split for this? Wouldn't a simple `var parts = Line.Split('\\')` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to escape the slash `"\\"` or make it a literal string `@"\"`.

Answer (score 3):

Why use a regex when [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) will do?

```
string[] parts = Line.Split('\\');
```

Comment: it cant, it must be a character then

Comment: @killie01 - No, it doesn't have to be. And `\` _is_ a character. Not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have escaped the \.

try \\

Answer (score 0):

Why not use String.Split() ?

And your trailing \ needs to be escaped thusly:  \

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is split a string into an array on a single character (backslash), try

```
string s = @"my\dog\has\fleas" ;
string[] words = s.split('\\') ;
```

Don't use a chainsaw if all you need is a paring knife.